# Full calendar license

Tags: javascript, ember.js, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

Our company bought a FullCalendar Saas license last month. A team mate used this license while prototyping a component that we are working on within the team. Now I am trying to use that same license on my machine and picking defaultView to be "timelineMonth", which is a premium feature, but I am getting this error "spec.class is not a constructor". When I use basic defaultView, things seem to be working fine. Any idea why this could be happening?

Comment: did you include the files for the Scheduler plugin? The error doesn't sound like a license error, but without seeing what you've done, who knows?

Comment: @ADyson that did it. great answer! thanks